# How to check option selected It was modified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<select class="select" id="choice-item" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="#opt0" selected="selected">32 bits</option>
    <option value="#opt1">64 bits</option>
</select>
```

I want to check if the user changed one option to another.

Answer (score 2):

[.change](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```js
$("#choice-item").change(function() {
  console.log("changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select" id="choice-item" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="#opt0" selected="selected">32 bits</option>
    <option value="#opt1">64 bits</option>
</select>
```

Comment: but if I click and select the same item he considers the change? I wanted when I did not do anything, just want to do if there is a change.